# IAsyncResult Begin/End pattern with Cancellation

Tags: c#, .net

I have a thread that uses `TcpClient`'s `BeginAcceptTcpClient()` method.  It resembles:

```
// this gets set elsewhere
ManualResetEvent _doneListening = new ManualResetEvent(false);
```

.. and in the thread procedure

```
while (true)
{
    var result = BeginAcceptTcpClient(null, null);

    var index = WaitHandle.WaitAny(new [] { _doneListening, result.AsyncWaitHandle });
    if (0 == index)
    {
        break;
    }

    // do something with EndAcceptTcpClient(result)
}
```

Now, according to MSDN's documentation:

> The asynchronous BeginAcceptTcpClient operation must be completed by
>   calling the EndAcceptTcpClient method.

My question relates to the *Cancel/Stop* case of my thread -- that is, after `_doneListening.Set()`--  I really don't want any more TcpClients.  At the same time, I don't want to leak memory.

Is it necessary to call EndAcceptTcpClient()?  This will block, and I certainly don't want it to (I want a fast thread exit).  But will it leak memory otherwise?  MSDN hints that Begin MUST be paired with an End.  Is there a different pattern I should follow for effectively cancelling a potentially in-progress async operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EndAcceptTcpClient` won't block if you've closed/disposed the TcpClient.  So when you are done listening then close it.  It will throw an exception in response to EndAcceptTcpClient, but that is OK.  You can safely ignore/discard the exception.

Answer (score 2):

It is recommended to call End* methods in the Begin/End pattern.  If you don't there's a few resources that will "leak".  You should call `TcpListener.Stop` to close the listener and then call `EndAcceptTcpClient`.

Stop may throw an exception if the listener becomes bound again.  So, you may need to check for that, or check `IsBound` (but between checking `IsBound` and `Stop` you could still get a new binding)...